# Google sheets - send email from from current user only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

In google sheets, I have it set it to when an user selects an option from a dropdown, it sends an email (from their email address) to the user who submitted that response on a form.  This part works fine.  The issue is that when an email is sent from the sheet, it sends an email from every user who authorized the script, not just the user that selected the option from the dropdown. I'm very green at this and not really sure how to fix it to where it only sends an email from the user who selected the option from the dropdown.

```
  function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [ {name: "Authorize", functionName: "createSpreadsheetEditTrigger"} ]
    ss.addMenu("First Time Setup", menuEntries);
 }
     //** Creates onEdit trigger using current user as owner.
      ** If other onEdit triggers exist tied to this document & owner, delete them to avoid  
      duplicates.**//
  function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var session = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
     triggers.forEach(function(trigger){
      if(trigger.getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT){
      scriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger); 
    }
 });
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendEmail')
   .forSpreadsheet(ss)
   .onEdit()
   .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('Denied')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onEdit()
  .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('Pending')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}


 Utilities.sleep(2000);
 function SendEmail(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

 try{
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
    }catch(e){
  return;
 }


 if(e.range.getColumn() == 22 && e.value == "Approved"){

  {
       var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
 
 
    
       var dt = e.range.offset(0,-21).getValue();
       var ldc = e.range.offset(0,-19).getValue();
       var status = e.range.offset(0,0).getValue();
       var notes = e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
       var cost = e.range.offset(0,-5).getValue();
       var start = e.range.offset(0,-4).getValue();
       var end = e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue();
       var Iemail = e.range.offset(0,-20).getValue();
       var Aemail = e.range.offset(0,4).getValue();
       var name = e.range.offset(0,-18).getValue();
       var issue = e.range.offset(0,-16).getValue(); 
       var emailSent = e.range.offset(0,5).getValue();
       var userName = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
    
          if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT){
           var subject = "Exception Bill Pre-Approval Status - Approved";
           var body = "Hello," + "\n\r" + "The following request has been Approved:" + "\n\n" + "Submitted on: " + dt
            + "\n" + "Submitted by: " + name + "\n" + "LDC: " + ldc + "\n" + "Service Needed: " + issue + "\n" + "Estimated Cost:" + cost + "\n" + "Start Date: " + start + "\n" + "End Date: " + end + "\n" + "Notes: " + notes + "\n\n" + "Status: " + status + "\n\r" + "\n\r" + "Thanks," + "\n" + userName;
            Utilities.sleep(2000);
          GmailApp.sendEmail(Iemail, subject, body);
          e.range.offset(0,5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT)
         SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Maybe not directly related to issue... Why do you have`Utilities.sleep(2000);` on the global scope? This affects all the executions and waste triggers execution daily quota.

Comment: I had issues with functions running simultaneously and needed them to run one after another.  Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Maybe. One option might be to use the Lock Service. If you need further help, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The email is being sent from every user because there is a trigger calling sendEmail created by each of them.

One solution is to add at the beginning of the function an if statement as follows:

```
if(e.user.getEmail() !== Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) return;
```